# wsgi:error pid 131476:tid 140411361216256 remote 200.110.48.158:35204 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'

Tags: python, django, wsgi, apache2.4

```
[Thu Jun 16 20:32:08.505090 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411386394368] [remote 193.32.127.157:53433] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 16 20:32:08.505133 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411386394368] [remote 193.32.127.157:53433]   File "/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server/server/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
[Thu Jun 16 20:32:08.505139 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411386394368] [remote 193.32.127.157:53433]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jun 16 20:32:08.505159 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411386394368] [remote 193.32.127.157:53433] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'
[Thu Jun 16 20:48:58.603180 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411361216256] [remote 200.110.48.158:35204] mod_wsgi (pid=131476): Failed to exec Python script file '/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server/server/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 16 20:48:58.603316 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411361216256] [remote 200.110.48.158:35204] mod_wsgi (pid=131476): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server/server/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 16 20:48:58.603447 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411361216256] [remote 200.110.48.158:35204] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 16 20:48:58.603477 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411361216256] [remote 200.110.48.158:35204]   File "/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server/server/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
[Thu Jun 16 20:48:58.603483 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411361216256] [remote 200.110.48.158:35204]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jun 16 20:48:58.603506 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 131476:tid 140411361216256] [remote 200.110.48.158:35204] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core'
```

## These are my all working files

```
**#000-default.conf**

<VirtualHost *:80>

        #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /root/novo-ai-api-main


        ErrorLog /root/novo-ai-api-main/error.log
        CustomLog /root/novo-ai-api-main/access.log combine


        <Directory /root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server/server>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                         Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /root/novo-ai-api-main/static
        <Directory /root/novo-ai-api-main/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>


        WSGIScriptAlias / /root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server/server/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/server  python-home=/root/novo-ai-api-main/backend/django/
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app

</VirtualHost>
#apache2.conf
**apache2.conf**
'''
<pre>
ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
Timeout 300
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
#same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5

#These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

LogLevel warn

#Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>


#AccessFileName .htaccess

#<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
#Require all denied
#</FilesMatch>


IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf


IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

#vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet



</pre>
'''
```

## i installed mod_wsgi correctly for python 3.8

```
 **#wsgi.py**

 import os, sys
 import site
 site.addsitedir('/root/novo-ai-api-main/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
 from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'server.settings')
 application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**permissions**

## also i have given permissions to all the working files but nothing happened

##### drwx--x--x  9 root     root       4096 Jun 16 22:05 .

```
drwxr-xr-x 19 root     root       4096 Jun 14 14:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root       4096 Jun 13 23:38 .local
drwxrwxr-x  8 root     root       4096 Jun 16 01:24 mod_wsgi-4.9.2
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 14 23:53 novo-ai-api-main <-(project)
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 14 23:14 backend
drw-r--r-- 8 www-data www-data     4096 Jun 14 00:33 static
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 14 00:16 django <- (venv) ####
```

## i have tried all the ways but couldn't solve this issue. please try to help me out as much as quickly

Answer (score 3):

In your `wsgi.py` try importing Django first (`import django`) and then after the line `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'server.settings')` add:

`django.setup()`

Check out the docs regarding this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage)

Also, you'll need to change the order of imports so that you import `get_wsgi_application` after you've done this.

Comment: Could you take a look at this post and suggest something to check? thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73263626/django-served-with-apache-how-to-set-pythonpath