# Django served with apache: how to set PYTHONPATH?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django app that works fine when served with the command "python manage.py runserver". Now I want to have the app served by Apache and got some issues.  One issue is that somehow I can't not set PYTHONPATH. I tried either of the following two ways to set it in a apache conf file:

```
WSGIPythonHome /data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb
WSGIPythonPath /data/partsdb/partsdb
```

or

```
WSGIDaemonProcess partsdb python-home=/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb python-path=/data/partsdb/partsdb
```

But I got errors saying PYTHONPATH = (not set).  Below is the whole error message from the apache server.

```
Current thread 0x00007fb4880ad940 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib64'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb'
  sys.path = [
    '/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb/lib64/python38.zip',
    '/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb/lib64/python3.8',
    '/data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb/lib64/python3.8/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

When I ran python (both /usr/bin/python3 and /data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb/bin/python3) from the commandline, I didn't get errors from the code **import encodings**.

The apache server kept running and when I tried to connect to the app with a browser, I got the following error after about 60 seconds.

```
Gateway Timeout

The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application.
```

Also I noticed these two lines **sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'** and **sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'**. Why /usr/bin/python3 instead of /data/anaconda3/envs/partsdb/bin/python3?  Although both are python3, their versions are different (one is 3.6.8 and the other 3.8.13.

Anyone have any ideas what might be the cause?  Thanks.

Edited:

Just to add that the apache conf file also has the following lines.

```
<Directory "/data/partsdb/partsdb">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

And the file wsgi.py was not changed since it was created when the project was created.  That is, it just contains the following codes.

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'partsdb.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Comment: @Mayanktaker the error was from the app and it's fixed by modifying the app's codes.